# Prevent First Chance Exception for TcpClient.Connect

Tags: c#, exception, tcp

I have a very frustrating First Chance Exception message in my code.

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
>   Additional information: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

```
private void RunThread()
{
    do
    {
        TcpClient client = null;
        StreamWriter writer = null;

        try
        {
            // Connect
            client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect(m_Hostname, m_PortNum);

            if (client.Connected) //No host available? EXCEPTION!
            {
                //Do stuff and exit listener thread
            }


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //dont care
        }
    } 
}
```

Now a brief explanation. The code in question is sat in a thread

1) This is a happily ignorable error! We can continue over it. But the problem is I'd have to disable the first chance exception (and so does everybody else) for the application to continue.

2) OK so lets say we disable the error. Thats fine, but because were in a thread and running into the exception constantly. We get this. Which gets VERY annoying when wanting to view the debug window.

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
>      A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
>      A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
>      A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
>      A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
>      A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
>      A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
>      A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
>      A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll

### Question

1. Can I poll the target host without throwing an exception?
2. If not, can I disable this assert? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the `DebuggerNonUserCode` attribute? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggernonusercodeattribute.aspx It should prevent the debugger from stepping through that method so that you don't get the notifications.

Comment: You sir are a GOD amongst men!